# Cannot install Google USB driver because it won't accept the driver

Tags: adb, usb-drivers

I tried

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb

I also tried

https://droidusb.com/download-lana-download/adb/

but that seems to be the same thing

and the google page tells me to go to device manager and "other devices",  I turned USB debugging on and that helped as then it showed under Other Devices.

It says MTP

[image]

So I went to settings..developer tools..usb configuration, and I switched it from MTP to PTP but it still sees MTP in device manager.

Is there some option I should be choosing that I haven't chosen yet?

Comment: slightly relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device/18515360#18515360

Comment: I did solve this but I can't recall what it was

Answer (score 1):

On Android 11, when you connect your device to your PC, assuming that USB debugging is already enabled, you will get a notification where it says what USB connection type is currently active. Tap on the notification. A menu should open where you can pick a USB connection type (MTP, PTP etc.). Pick "*No file transfer*" and try installing the Google USB Driver again. Use the Device Manager, find your Android device, right-click, update drivers, select my own and select the folder where the Google USB Driver for Windows is located.